# problem in converting "vue-enterprise-boilerplate" to typescript base?

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, enterprise

i'm trying to use  typescript in **vue-enterprise-boilerplate**.  but there are some problems with the flow has been said in this issue https://github.com/chrisvfritz/vue-enterprise-boilerplate/issues/118 .

i tried other solutions to make it work, like using "vue add @vue/typescript", there is no clear explanation about which config should i pick.

```
1? Use class-style component syntax?(y/N)
2? Use Babel alongside TypeScript (required for modern mode, auto-detected polyfills, transpiling JSX)? (y/N)
3? Convert all .js files to .ts? (y/N)
4? Allow .js files to be compiled? (y/N)
```

number 3q, is telling me to choose babel to modern , while in that issue the author telling:

> Use @vue/cli-plugin-typescript instead of @vue/cli-plugin-babel (while deleting .babelrc.js).

and i did that too, but i got some new error about can not find some modules, and when i tried to fix them, there has been some new error with webpack config...
is there anyone who tried this steps and the has a working step-by-stp-solution about this problem.